# VNC Showing Grey Screen

Tags: 16.04, vnc, vncviewer, tightvncserver

The screen is showing this strange grey/black image when I use VNC. None of my files can be accessed and I can't do anything. It is Ubuntu 16.04. Please any suggestions are needed.

Comment: It sounds like you're seeing the default `~/.vnc/xstartup`: did you actually configure anything different?

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to change off the default

Comment: Have a look here first [VNC/Servers: Customising your session](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers#Customising_your_session). FWIW I don't recommend trying to run a Unity-based desktop over VNC - simple sessions such as xfce4 or LXDE seem to work best.